# Automatically give Apache write permissions to newly added git clone files (-R g+rw)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, permissions, wordpress

I'm having a problem with allowing Apache to automatically have write access to an .htaccess file being pulled from a git repository.

Here's my process:

I'm logged in as a newly created user "**webadmin**", which has been added to the group "***apache***" (i'm on CentOS so it's equivalent to *www-data*) and I have created an empty directory:

`/var/www/html/test`

I've ensured that on this directory, i've done the following:

```
$ umask 002 
$ chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/test
$ chmod -R g+rw /var/www/html/test
```

This is to make sure that the directory is owned by the *group* "***apache***", and since my *user* "***webadmin***" is part of that group, I assume that anything I add with this user will also be writeable by the ***apache*** user (php scripts).

Still using the ***webadmin*** user, I then run a

`git clone myrepo.git .`

Which pulls my WordPress website files down into the directory.  Included in this is an .htaccess file.  This file needs to be writeable by WordPress, so that it can modify rules.  All files pulled down are owned by ***webadmin*** with the group of ***apache***.

For whatever reason, the .htaccess file is not by default writeable by apache until i again run:

```
$ chmod -R g+rw /var/www/html/test
```

Why would I have to run this command again?  Is there any way I can make it so that this file can but automatically written to by apache when it's pulled down without having to run the `-R g+rw` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your need is exactly opposite of [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574271/git-change-default-umask-when-update-file). So in short, you can choose to:

- Set umask appropriately (presumably to 002, according to your post) before running `git`
- Add a git hook script to change file permission after cloning.

The first choice is generally easier to do.

Comment: Thanks, so basically you are saying it needs to be done every time before running a git clone?

Comment: Yes, but of course you would have easier life if the umask can be set automatically before running git clone. There's no enough info on how you are running git so the "correct" way depends. For example, if you're running `git` from PHP script, then you would want to take a look at [PHP `umask()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php).